# Filtering .ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm new to ASP.NET MVC. What I have:
- database with one table which contains production data in following columns:
machine_name, good_parts, bad_parts, date.

Based on MS tutorial to ASP.NEt MVC5 i have build simple application to display data from database.

What I want:
I want to filter the results by machine_name, because there is too many records in DB, and browser hangs while rendering results.

Controller looks like that:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View(db.DATABASE.ToList());

        }
```

View page:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.machine_name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.good_parts)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bad_parts)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.machine_name == "machine_1")
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.machine_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.data)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.good_parts)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.bad_parts)
        </td>
      </tr> 
     }
}
```

After implementing if statement, view does not return any records from DB.
Thanks a lot in advance for your time explaining me the basics.

Marcin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its as easy as

```
db.DATABASE.Where(x => x.MachineName == "something").ToList()
```

or

```
db.DATABASE.Take(100).ToList()
```

---

[Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[Queryable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

[Enumerable.Take(IEnumerable, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[QueryableExtensions.Take Method (IQueryable, Expression>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.take(v=vs.113).aspx)

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
db.DATABASE.Where(item=>item.machine_name =="machine1").ToList();
```